# Unable to use _parent in target attribute HTML

Tags: html, attributes, parent, target

I am trying to use the target attribute with _parent as its value.

Here is the first code

```
<html>
<head></head>

<frameset rows="30%,70%" >

            // About Frame1
            <frame src="" name="" />

            // about Frame2
            <frameset  cols="50%,50%">
            <frame src="targetattribute_file1.html" name="" />
            <frame src="" name="" />
            </frameset>

</frameset>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my second file (targetattribute_file1.html )

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_parent">Click here  for youtube</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It opens the file in a full window instead of opening in the parent frame. Wats wrong with code??

Comment: Framesets are wrong with the code. Don’t use frames for anything. Anyway, the nesting of frameset elements doesn’t change what `_parent` refers to, and link targets can’t change the frame structure on their own; you would have to create a new page with a new frameset and embed that as a frame to get this behaviour.

Comment: @minitech i am not able to understand what you are saying. Can you ellaborate a bit.